# ngOnChanges working only when there is an action

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngonchanges

I create my own upload file component using XMLHttpRequest and everything works fine... The only issue that I have is that I create a callback method which update the progress of the upload so the user can see the percentage.

If I do a consolo.log() of the progrees, I can see how it increase from 0 to 100.

But the screen doesn't reflect that... I have this function in that component:

```
ngOnChanges(){
if(this.progress == 100){
  this.progress = 0;
  this.uploading = false;
}
 }
```

And I have a method to get the latest value of the progress (which is fired from the parent component)

```
public updateProgress(progress : number){
    this.progress = progress;
    console.log(this.progress);
    if(this.progress == 100)
      this.uploading = false;
  }
```

And if the template I have

```
    <div *ngIf="uploading" class="uploading">
    <progressbar [max]="100" [value]="progress"><span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap;">{{progress}} / {{100}}</span></progressbar>
</div>
```

So the progress bar is not increasing the progress even when in the console I can see that the value is of 'progress' changing..

But after long time, I discover that if do a click with the mouse in ANY section of the screen the ngOnChange is fired, and the progress bar is updated... So If I start doing clicks while the file is being upload I'm able to see the progress...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

and after you update `progress`, call

```
this.progress = ...;
this.cdRef.markForCheck();
```

or

```
this.progress = ...;
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

alternatively you can inject `NgZone`

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone){}
```

and do the update with

```
this.zone.run(() => this.progress = ...);
```

This causes change detection to run when Angular code is called from outside Angular in a way that Angular isn't able to recognize it.

Comment: Thanks! I used the zone option and it works like a charm!

Comment: Glad to hear :) If this answers your question, please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed **implements OnChanges**

```
import {Component,OnChanges, SimpleChange} from '@angular/core';
  export class yourcomponet implements OnChanges {
   ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange})
    {
      // Here goes your logic
   }
}
```

Comment: I have this in the component
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't listed all the code, it's not clear how you parent/child components communicate. On one hand, it seems that both parent and child have the variable progress. Why?

The other question is why are you using ngOnChanges?

If your child component knows the current value of progress, create an @Output variable in the child and emit an event on each progress change.

```
@Output() currentProgres: EventEmitter <number> = new EventEmitter();
...
this.currentProgress.emit(progress);
```

In the parent, listen to these events:

```
<progressbar [max]="100" (currentProgress)="updateProgress($event)">
...
updateProgress(progress : number){}
```

The parent can have a variable showProgress bound to the UI so it'll update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

from the example I can see that in your child component you are inputting the property called **value** but in method checking **progress**. make sure you are putting it into a local property progress. ngOnChanges() will fire every time any input property changes. try to print console.log in your ngOnChanges() before any if() statement and check the **value**